# React Native - NetInfo.fetch() returns false on network change in the background

Tags: android, facebook, react-native

I am using [react-native-sync-adapter](https://github.com/ferrannp/react-native-sync-adapter) in my [react-native](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/) `Android` app. The sync service triggers a function at every fixed interval in the background.

I use the following function to check for internet availability in the trigger.

```
export function isNetworkConnected() {
  return NetInfo.fetch().then(reachability => {
    if (reachability === 'unknown') {
      return new Promise(resolve => {
        const handleFirstConnectivityChangeIOS = isConnected => {
          NetInfo.isConnected.removeEventListener('change', handleFirstConnectivityChangeIOS);
          resolve(isConnected);
        };
        NetInfo.isConnected.addEventListener('change', handleFirstConnectivityChangeIOS);
      });
    }
    reachability = reachability.toLowerCase();
    return (reachability !== 'none' && reachability !== 'unknown');
  });
}
```

On a **real device**, when I disable `WiFi`, open the app (the app also calls the same method on launch and sets the state of connectivity to `false`), push the app to the background again and enable `WiFi`, `isNetworkConnected()` returns `false` always.

What can be possibly wrong?

*PS: react-native version 0.42.3*

Comment: Don't know the reason and I happened to me also. Netinfo.fetch() makes a request, so instead of that you can make a lightweight get request using `fetch()` and check internet